# get result from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table (lecture_table)

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| lecture_name  | lecturer_name  | class              |day| start|end  |
|-------------- +--------------- +--------------------+----------------|
| Electronics 2 | Jhon Rayan     | Engineering Class 2| 0 | 8.5  |11.5 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I try to build a search page about day in the above table but I have some problems 
the day that i used in my data base is an integer number (0 means sunday,1 means monday....)
I need to type in search panel for example sunday which mean 0 in database then get the result and display it as Sunday not 0
the query i used to get result is as below

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT lecture_name, 
                                lecturer_name, 
                                class,
                                start, 
                                end, 
                                CASE day
                                    WHEN 0 THEN 'Sunday'
                                    WHEN 1 THEN 'Monday'
                                    WHEN 2 THEN 'Tuesday'
                                    WHEN 3 THEN 'Wednesday'
                                    WHEN 4 THEN 'Thursday'
                                    WHEN 5 THEN 'Friday'
                                    WHEN 6 THEN 'Saturday'
                                    ELSE 'Unknown'
                                END AS x
                        FROM lecture_table WHERE (`day` LIKE '%".$name."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

so what I should use before above query to convert my input search from Sunday to 0 to compare my entry with data base.

Comment: What's 8.5? Is that 8:30?

Comment: So a lecturer only teaches a given lecture once a week?

Comment: Why not just convert between "Sunday" and "0" in your code, outside of SQL?

Comment: let me show you what i need, when i search lectures for Sunday the value of search i converted from Sunday to 0 then check lectures for 0 day in data base and then when i want to display the result again convert 0 to Sunday and display the result of Sunday with lecture name start time.......

Comment: What I think @jessepinho is saying is when you write 'Sunday', why not have the code search for '0'

Comment: Exactly. Looks like you're using PHP, so: `$days = array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');` And then in your query: `"...FROM lecture_table WHERE (day = " . array_search($day_name, $days) . '"..."` Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
SELECT lecture_name, lecturer_name, class, start, end, day_name
 FROM lecture_table l JOIN 
(
    SELECT 0 day, 'Sunday' day_name UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'Monday' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Tuesday' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'Wednesday' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'Thursday' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'Friday' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 'Saturday'
) d ON l.day = d.day
WHERE day_name = 'Sunday'
```

Output:

```
|  LECTURE_NAME | LECTURER_NAME |               CLASS | START |  END | DAY_NAME |
|---------------|---------------|---------------------|-------|------|----------|
| Electronics 2 |    Jhon Rayan | Engineering Class 2 |   8.5 | 11.5 |   Sunday |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c659d/2)** demo

---

> what if i want results for another day such as Monday,... how can i apply it

If you want only records for Monday

```sql
... WHERE day_name = 'Monday'
```

If you want records for several days

```sql
... WHERE day_name IN('Monday', 'Wednesday', 'Friday')
```

Of course instead of using exact values you will interpolate query string with php variable, e.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT ... WHERE day_name = '$name'"; // Don't forget validate and sanitize user input
```

or **better** switch to **PDO/mysqli** and  use **prepared statements**.

Comment: thank you for your reply i check it and its exactly what i want but what if i want results for another day such as Monday,... how can i apply it since you are used WHERE day_name = 'Sunday' i put my code instead of just sunday but it didnt work                          WHERE day_name LIKE '%".$name."%')")                                     could you advise please?